# Can SQLAlchemy's reflection tools output python source?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to reflect a schema using SQLAlchemy's `MetaData.reflect()` method, so that I can have a cache of the current schema. How can I do this?

Comment: Is what you're asking provided by meta = MetaData(stuff); meta.reflect(); meta.tables[tablename]?

Comment: Yes, but I want it output in such a way as to be useable to create a test fixture in Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and supported way to cache the result of reflection is to just pickle the MetaData object. If you prefer to generate Python code that initializes the metadata, then there's a tool called [sqlautocode](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/).

Comment: I've tried it; wow, does it ever NOT work properly with SQLAlchemy 0.6; I had to patch a bunch of its imports to make it work. It can be done, however.